# How can I trigger a function when switching sheets within a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

How can I trigger a function when switching sheets?

Let's say I'm viewing a multi-sheet spreadsheet. Now I want a function to run whenever I switch from one sheet (tab) to another.
[image: Tabs in a spreadsheet]
Is that possible?

There is the `onOpen` trigger, but that only runs when I first open the spreadsheet - not when opening other sheets within that spreadsheet:

Comment: I have created a "**Feature request**" to implement "onSheetChange" trigger at google issue tracker. You can star it, so google now you want this:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72140210 And here is related question with possible workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506382/how-to-capture-change-tab-event-in-google-spreadsheet/48318897#48318897

Answer (score 3):

As Rubén says, there's no such event built in. But you *might* have some (limited) success with this approach:

```
var PROP_NAME = "lastSheetIdx";
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();

function didSwitchSheets(from, to) {
  Logger.log("Switched from " + from + " to " + to);
  // Your code here
}

function timedEventHandler() {
  var currentSheetIdx = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getIndex()
  var previousSheetIdx = parseInt(userProperties.getProperty(PROP_NAME));
  if (currentSheetIdx !== previousSheetIdx) {
    didSwitchSheets(previousSheetIdx, currentSheetIdx);
    userProperties.setProperty(PROP_NAME, currentSheetIdx);
  }
}
```

Paste this code, press the *Run* button to authorize the script (you only need to do this once).
Then, from the *Resources* menu, select *Triggers for current script*, and set up the `timedEventHandler` to run as often as you can - which currently seems to be "every minute".

That will cause the function to run every minute and check if the "current sheet" id has changed, and if so, the `didSwitchSheets` function will run.

Probably, one minute is not often enough. But it might look as though Google is about to implement the possibility to run a script every second. At least that comes up as a choice in my *Triggers for current script* dialog, but it does not seem to work when I select it - see [Can I set a trigger to run every second?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/91823/can-i-set-a-trigger-to-run-every-second)

I have created [an example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HT3aNUSpsOnL0oNYqPObf8XnMJ5ID90clgJAKAAx1iM/edit?usp=sharing) to demonstrate this. Not much to see there, but make a copy of it (File → Copy) to your own Google Drive, and you should be able to see and edit the script as much as you like.

Comment: Another (better?) approach could be to use [SpreadsheetApp.setActivesheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#setactivesheetsheet) to switch between sheets by using a script instead of using tabs and including in that script a call to the function to be run when switching from one sheet to another.

Comment: @Vidar S. Ramel, Yes, you pointed out a good option. But it is like a cron job which checks every minute and runs the script accordingly. But this does not fit my requirement. May I know, whether we can restrict viewing a specific sheet from others in a multisheet spredasheet ? I know this is entirely different from my actual question. But I am just asking. :)

Comment: You should post that as a separate question. And search for it first, it might already have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: On [April 2020](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#april_22_2020) Google added [onSelectionChange(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee) which could be used to check if the user switched between sheets aka tabs.

---

At this time there isn't a trigger related to switch for one sheet to another. To learn about the available triggers in Google Apps Script, please checkout [Triggers and events - Google Apps Script  Guides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)