# Can I set a trigger to run every second?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

While searching for answer to [How can I trigger a function when switching sheets within a spreadsheet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/91812/how-can-i-trigger-a-function-when-switching-sheets-within-a-spreadsheet) I noticed that the *Triggers for current project* dialog has an option for specifying a trigger interval in *seconds*.

That is, in the first drop-down menu (`a`), I select *On time*, and in the next (`b`) I select *Timer, seconds* (`a`):

[image: The Triggers for current project dialog]

Now I would expect the drop-down menu `c` to contain the items *Every second*, *Every 2 seconds*, *Every 4 seconds* and so on. However, it lists the options *Every **hour***, *Every 2 **hours*** etc - as if I had selected *Timer, hours* in `a`.

This looks like a bug, right? Or is there another way to set up a trigger that runs every X seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using English as the main language in the Google account settings the options for the second drop-down (b) are

- Minutes timer
- Hour timer
- Day timer
- Week timer
- Month timer

There isn't a seconds timer, so it's very likely that there is localization error. Use the [Google Apps Script Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) to report it to Google.

Comment: You must be right. I have created https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5926&thanks=5926&ts=1460469673. Thanks!