# Scheduling a script to run at a specific time rather than a range of time

Tags: google-apps-script

I set a time-driven trigger to run my script, but the only choices in the pull-down menu for this are 1 hour ranges, 1-2pm, 2-3pm, etc. I chose 1-2pm, and one day the macro ran at 1:38pm and another day it ran at 1:42pm. I would really like the script to run at exactly 1pm. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Apps Script hasn't a built-in way to make a trigger to run exactly at certain time as setting a trigger to run a certain time has a +/- 15 minutes variation.

One workaround is to use a time-driven trigger to run every minute an include a condition to make some part of the code to execute if the current execution is running at the desired time.

Here is a starting base:

```
function runEveryMinute(){
  const date = new Date();
  const hours = date.getHours();
  const minutes = date.getMinutes();
  if(hours === 13 && minutes === 0){
   // do something
  } else {
   // do nothing
  }
}
```

You should have to refine the above i.e. instead of using `minutes === 0` you might want to use another condition and a way to check if the task was not already don in order to handle possible variations on the start execution time, like using a spreadsheet or the Properties Service to log timestamp of the last execution of the code part.

Also you might have to implement some measures to prevent consuming the installable triggers execution time daily quota, like creating / deleting the trigger that will run every minute few minutes before / after the desired time.

---

A more "elegant solution" might be to have a combination of time-driven triggers, i.e one that run daily near the desired time. If it run too early, it should create a trigger to run time [after certain milliseconds](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#after(Integer)) before the desired time and iterate using do or while loops until the desired time is reached.

This might require to keep the logs to make the necessary adjustments based on performance and reliability.

Related

- [Google Apps Script Time Based Trigger Date and Hour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30448784/1595451)
- [Can I set a trigger to run every second?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/91823/88163)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and base code. Your suggestion got me thinking that I could schedule the function to run 12-1pm, query the time when it does run, calculate how long that is before 1pm, sleep for the necessary time, and then perform my action (which should happen at 1pm). Thanks again.

Comment: Actually I discovered my modification to your idea does not work because there is a time limit for functions to complete of 6 minutes. So if the trigger starts the function more than 6 minutes before 1pm, trying to sleep until 1pm will cause the function to time out.

Comment: @MarkNeal Thanks for keeping us posted. P.S. Google Workspace accounts have a 30 min execution time limit but I don't think that it's worthy to consume part of the daily quota keeping an execution sleeping for so many minutes. Take a look to  this option https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#after(Integer)

Comment: I think the way you originally suggested will work, but I really don't want to run the function every minute all the time just for it to actually do something only once per week. So I did the second part of what you suggested with the code in the next comment.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to post code so it is readable. Anyway, I wrote a functionA to create a trigger for my action function to run every minute. I wrote another functionB to delete the trigger. My action function checks if the minute == 0. If it is it performs my action. If not, it does nothing. I run functionA and it creates the trigger and my action function starts running every minute. At the top of the hour it does perform my action. I then run functionB, which deletes the trigger. All this works fine. But when I try to do this by setting triggers for functionA and functionB, it fails.

Comment: So I set a trigger to run functionA at 12-1pm and a trigger to run functionB at 1-2pm. At some random time functionA starts, but I can see from my execution log that my action function never runs. I check my Triggers, and the two for functionA and functionB are there. The trigger for my action function is also there but it says in red letter "Disabled." I click on it and it says "Trigger was disabled for unknown reason." So this worked fine if I just manually run functionA, but is does not work if I set a trigger to run functionA. Maybe they don't like triggered functions creating triggers?

Comment: I will try to figure out how to post readable code and do that.